# Filter data view web part by page field

Tags: view, data

Is there a way to filter a data view by a page field that exist on the page. 
We can Implement it by CQWP in this way: [PageFieldValue: Relevancy].

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create a custom data view and filter it using a Parameter which is based on a control, that is part of your layout or one that you've added on the page, after adding your control, create a new data view parameter based on that control, and add "ItemFieldValue", after the control id, Please see the image attached for better understanding.
[image: Adding a control based parameter in a data view]